Is the derivative at a point x of a smooth real-valued map linear?
I am currently reading "Differential Topology" by Victor Guillemin and Alan Pollack. They are in the process of explaining the preimage theorem in terms of a set of common zeroes (to show that such a set is a manifold) of smooth real-valued maps $g_1,\dots g_{l}$ on a manifold $X$. They argue that "Since each $g_{i}$ is a smooth map of $X$ into $\mathbb{R}$, its derivative at a point $x$ is a linear map $d(g_{i})_{x}: T_{x}(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, that is, $d(g_{i})_{x}$ is a linear functional on the vector space $T_{x}(X)$."
However, I am  struggling to comprehend how one can know/claim such a thing. I do not remember it being mentioned that smooth maps automatically have derivatives that for each point $x$ correspond to a linear map, and it's hard for me to see the logic in it. Could someone help and explain how this can be the case and one can conclude this?

The derivative is a linear map whenver it exists, by definition. Ref. Baby Rudin

Hi @SassatelliGiulio, thank you for you answer, in that case I have to do some more research/develop some intuition into why the derivative is a linear map.

@Tosca It is by definition. Differentials (or derivatives) are defined to approximate linearly some functions around a given point, like tangents approximate curves around their common point.

@Didier, are you implying that it is locally linear?

@Tosca absolutely not

Standard multivariable analysis (including a reasonable understanding of the derivative as a linear map and the inverse function theorem) is a definite prerequisite for reading Guillemin and Pollack. I'm not fond of baby Rudin for this material, but you can take a look at some of my YouTube lectures (linked in my profile) to develop some of this background.

@TedShifrin Thank you so much! Some of my issues with understanding the material have to do with how everything is generalized to manifolds, and how to "convert" my current understanding of standard multivariate analysis and understand it intuitively at the level of manifolds as well. But I worry I may have missed out on some important material or forgotten something relevant, so I will certainly take a look.
